# classLoader.getResource returns null

Tags: java, java-ee, maven

веб проект, деплоится на tomcat с помощью maven.
Создал папку resources, пометил как resources root. Как прочитать из нее? Вычитал способ - https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/
но почему то у меня не работает. url = null

```
private final String xmlBlankFileName = "Blank_Envelope.xml";
private final String xmlDataFileName = "Data_Envelope.xml";
private Document doc;

public EncryptXmlCreator() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL url = classLoader.getResource(xmlBlankFileName);
        //InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(xmlBlankFileName);
        //URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).getURLs();
        if (url != null)
        {
            File xmlFile = new File(url.getFile());
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Пробовал по разному указывать путь

```
private final String xmlBlankFileName = "/Envelope.xml";
private final String xmlBlankFileName1 = "Envelope.xml";
```

И по разному получить путь к файлу

```
URL url = classLoader.getResource(xmlBlankFileName);
URL url1 = classLoader.getResource(xmlBlankFileName1);
URL url2 = getClass().getResource(xmlBlankFileName);
URL url3 = getClass().getResource(xmlBlankFileName1);
InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(xmlBlankFileName);
```

Посмотрел содержимое war файла - ресурсов нет. Надо что то добавить в pom.xml, чтобы ресурсы включались в варник?

Здесь много модулей, конкретно в этом никаких настроек для ресурсов нет.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>klab</artifactId>
        <groupId>klab</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>ers</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <glassfish.remoteHost>192.168.1.29</glassfish.remoteHost>
        <deploy.containerId>tomcat7x</deploy.containerId>
        <!--<org.hibernate-version>5.4.4.Final</org.hibernate-version>-->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>klab</groupId>
            <artifactId>global</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Покажи, что находится в результатирующем war'нике (это zip-архив). Интересует всё внутри `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: Посмотрел содержимое war файла - ресурсов нет. Надо что то добавить в pom.xml, чтобы ресурсы включались в варник?

Comment: По умолчанию для maven'а исходники лежат в `scr/main/java`, а ресурсы в `src/main/resources`. И он в этом случае должен их подтянуть. Если, конечно, ты не изменил как-то конфиги maven в `pom.xml`

Comment: а зачем тогда помечать папку resources root? я кидал папку resources в src/resources и в корень проекта. Структура проекта немного отличается от общепринятой main - resources root, а java - нет. Проект делали до меня, что есть то есть. http://skrinshoter.ru/s/081119/GdkPUDvu?a

Comment: Эти пометки ты делаешь для своей IDE (Eclipse или JetBrains IDEA). Maven ничего не знает об этих пометках. Приложи содержимое `pom.xml`.

Comment: Здесь много модулей, конкретно в этом никаких настроек для ресурсов нет. там только подключение спринг и общего модуля.

Answer (score 0):

Переопределил дефолтную директорию ресурсов и все заработало

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```